# Update variables passed with django include tag

Tags: django

I have a for loop that contains an include tag like the following:

```
{% for thing in things %}                                       
                                                                
    {% block example %}                                     
        {% include 'myapp/example.html' with thing=thing %}
    {% endblock %}

{% endfor %}
```

I expected that the html in `example.html` would get rendered with each `thing` within `things` but it only gets rendered with the first `thing` object. Is there a way to pass each of the `thing` objects within `things` to `example.html`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is supposed to work, even with the `{% block %}` tags, as long as you do not redefine them somewhere else. Maybe the problem is on the `things` or `myapp/example.html` side?

Note: if you refer to `thing` with the same identifier in your child template, you don't need the `with thing=thing` part - for exemple, `{{ thing }}` will be directly avalaible in your child template.

Something you might want to try:

```
{% for thing in things %}                                                 
    {% include 'myapp/example.html' %}
    {{ thing }}
{% endfor %}
```